# Jenkins variable with multiple values

Tags: jenkins

I want my job to be parametrized. The thing is that I want to select a unique parameter with multiple values.

I have a unique parameter named **"var"** with 2 options (1, 2) and then set of values linked to each option:

> Parameter name: var -> values: 1,2

- One set of values:

> - value1: "1.0.0"
> - value2: "myname"
> - value3:"build/libs"

- Another set of values:

> - value1: "2.0.0"
> - value2: "myname2"
> - value3: "var/lib"

In the "Build section" I select "Execute shell" with the following lines:

```
echo ${var.value1}
echo ${var.value2}
echo ${var.value3}
```

So when building the job I would like to select from a dropdown list with 2 values as said above: 1 and 2.

If I select 1, I would like to take the first set of values so that it would dislplay:

```
1.0.0
myname
build/libs
```

On the other hand if I select 2, I would like to display the second set of values:

```
2.0.0
myname2
var/lib
```

I have tried "Extended Choice Parameter plugin" but I don´t know how to manage this situation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution to this is you could do assignment of the variables in bash. So you create parameter number with options of ONE and TWO. Then in the "execute shell" section do something like:

```
if [ ${NUMBER} = "ONE" ]; then
   num_array=(1.0.0 myname build)
else
   num_array=(2.0.0 myname2 build)
fi
echo ${num_array[0]}
echo ${num_array[1]}
echo ${num_array[2]}
```

It's not the cleanest way but should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the approach. But I´m facing the following build error: "/tmp/jenkins845127605497968653.sh: 3: /tmp/jenkins845127605497968653.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "fi")" @NickBrown

Comment: sorry made an edit there, hopefully that should work. If not could you just run it in a separate script in the command line to check that the script works.

Comment: Yes it works in Shell but not in Jenkins. I will manage to work this out! Thank you!

Comment: I found the solution. Above the code we have to add: "#!/bin/bash". Thanks again for your help